# SSIS Expression

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

```
 SELECT CAST(Count(1) as VARCHAR(30)) AS SourceRowCount 
 FROM table 
 where countryid= '" +@[User::Id] +"'"+ " "+"
 AND locationid ="'+@[User::ID1]+'"
```

Expected output

```
 SELECT CAST(Count(1) as VARCHAR(30)) AS SourceRowCount 
 FROM table 
 where countryid= 1 
 AND locationid =2
```

Comment: I edited your question to format your code. Now what's your actual problem?

Comment: No question was asked

Comment: Hi ,   I tried below expression and got error. please help me                                                                                                           SELECT CAST(Count(1) as VARCHAR(30)) AS SourceRowCount 
 FROM table 
 where countryid= '" +@[User::Id] +"'"+ " "+"
 AND locationid ="'+@[User::ID1]+'"

Answer (score 1):

Use an Execute SQL Task step in your Control Flow to execute the query, passing the two variable values in as parameters, and return the value into another variable, https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/ .